How to give every element of an array a ref in Typescript?
I have a component that renders multiple things, one of that is an array of spans.
Here is a part of my code:
class MyComponent ... {
  private targetSpan = HTMLElement;

  componentDidMount() {
    //Here I get some data that fills an array that has 6 values
  }

   ...
   ...
   ...

  private setActive(value) {
    let target = this.targetSpan;

    if (target.classList.contains('active')) {
      target.classList.remove('active');
      //do more things
    }
    else {
      target.classList.add('active');
      //do even more things
    }
  }

  private splitMyThings() {
    const returnThings: any[] = [];

    forEach(array, thing => {
      returnThings.push(
        <span class="thing" onClick={() => this.setActive(thing)} ref={elem => this.targetSpan = elem}>
          {thing}
        </span>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
  ...

    return <div class="container">
      ...
      <div class="myTargets">
        {this.splitMyThings()}
      </div>
      ...
    </div>;
  }
}

When I watch the result in a Browser, all the spans show up how I want, only thing that doesnt seem to work correctly is the setActive-Function (or even something else?).
No matter what span I click, everytime only the last one gets the active-class, I absolutely cant figure out how to fix that.
Hope someone has a quick and simple solution or idea how to achieve that,
thanks in advance!

It would be simpler to use event.target in the onClick handler instead of a ref.

You're setting this.targetSpan to each element, overriding the assignment on every iteration. I'm not quite sure how you expect this to work?

Here's an example of how you should being approaching something like this:
import { Component, render } from 'preact';

const CSS_TEXT = `
    .thing {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .selected {
        color: red;
    };
`;

class MyComponent extends Component {
    state = {
        // index of the selected item -- if your list items can change, you'll want a better identifier, such as the text.
        selectedIdx: -1, 
        array: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Just creating an array as you mention in the post
        this.setState({ array: Array.from({ length: 6 }).map((_, i) => i) });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <style>{CSS_TEXT}</style>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.array.map((thing, i) => (
                        <li
                            class={this.state.selectedIdx == i ? 'selected' : ''}
                            onClick={() => this.setState({ selectedIdx: i })}
                        >
                            {thing}
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('app'));

Can test it in the Preact REPL
Refs are not the way, nor are DOM APIs like .classList. You also should not be using a forEach loop to iterate over one list and populate another -- this is what .map is for.
Changed up your example slightly for a better demo, (making the array a list instead of spans, adding in CSS for the selected items), but it should be easy to translate back.

Thank you so much for this example. It took me quite a while (still a newbie), but now it works!! :)

You are attempting to mutate "thing" using the setActive function.
But when looking at setActive(value) you never actually do anything with value in this context, but instead pull it from your class with , but instead derive it from let target = this.targetSpan;

In this context i use 'value' for some other tasks. I even tried now to give the function two parameters (this, value) and in the function I say 'let target = event.target', but it still isnt working..
